# Posicionamento dos scripts e links css num documento html

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, dom

Sempre coloquei os scripts e os links ao CSS na parte superior do documento no head do documento. Agora percebo que há um outro conceito em que as chamadas aos scripts e CSS, ficam na parte inferior do documento `html`, nas últimas linhas do `body`.

Há uma razão para isso? Um colega meu me deu uma explicação há tempos, mas não lembro do todo. É melhor mesmo? Tem vantagens técnicas? Gostaria de saber a respeito.

Answer (score 4):

### A tag `<script>`

A razão pra colocar os scripts no final `<body>` é [simples](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom): o download dos scripts bloqueiam downloads paralelos. A especificação HTTP/1.1 sugere que os navegadores não tentem baixar mais do que dois componentes de um mesmo host em paralelo. Se você hospeda suas imagens em hosts diferentes, você pode obter mais que dois downloads em paralelo.

Porém, no caso dos scripts, o navegador não fará nenhum outro download, mesmo que de hosts diferentes.

Ou seja, sua página fica "bloqueada" enquanto o script estiver sendo carregado, tornando a experiência do usuário mais lenta.

### As tags `<link>` e `<script>`

De acordo com a especificação do W3, [a tag `<link>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) e a [tag `<style>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-style-element) só podem ser colocadas entre as tags `<head>`.

Portanto, coloca-las dentro da tag `<body>` é inválido.

Comment: eu tenho colocado linhas assim no final do body e tem funcionado:  <link href="~/Content/Agendamento.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: @pnet Funciona pois seu browser é esperto. Mas não torna seu html válido. Na dúvida, use o [verificador](http://validator.w3.org/) do W3.

Answer (score 3):

**Posicionamento dos scripts e links css num documento html**

A especificação HTML 4 e 5 indica que uma tag *script* deve ser posicionada dentro de uma tag *head* ou *body* em um documento HTML e que pode aparecer um número qualquer de vezes em cada uma delas. Tradicionalmente, tags *script* utilizadas para carregar arquivos JavaScript externos aparecem em *head*, junto de tags *link* para carregar arquivos CSS externos e outras metainformações sobre a página. A teoria era a de que é melhor manter o máximo de dependências de estilo e comportamento juntas, carregando-as primeiro para que a página surja e se comporte corretamente.

**Exemplo de posicionamento JavaScript ineficiente:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Script Example</title>
       <-- Exemplo de posicionamento JavaScript ineficiente -->
       <script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="file3.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <p>Hello world!</p>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Ainda que esse código possa parecer inócuo, ele apresenta um problema de desempenho grave: há três arquivos JavaScript sendo carregados no *head*. Uma vez que cada tag *script* impede que a página continue a ser renderizada até que o código JavaScript carregue e execute totalmente, o desempenho aparente dessa página será penalizado. Tenha em mente que navegadores não começam a renderizar nada na página até que a tag *body* de abertura seja encontrada. Colocar scripts no topo da página desse modo geralmente leva a uma demora perceptível, muitas vezes na forma de uma página vazia em branco, antes que o usuário possa começar a ler e interagir com o documento.

**Exemplo do posicionamento recomendado do script**

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Script Example</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
   </head>
   <body>
     <p>Hello world!</p>
     <-- Exemplo do posicionamento recomendado do script -->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="file3.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Uma vez que os scripts bloqueiam o download de todos os tipos de recursos da página, é recomendado que todas as tags *script* sejam posicionadas o mais próximo possível do fim da tag *body* para que não afetem o download da página.

Para mais informações o sobre posicionamento de js e css. Veja: https://novatec.com.br/livros/javascriptdesemp/capitulo9788575222416.pdf