# Chamar função js em outro arquivo - Dependência entre scripts Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou com dúvida no js para chamar uma função em outro js.

Exemplo:

```
if (nome == ""){
   exibirModal();
}
```

Como a função "`exibirModal()`" está em outro js, está dando erro como se a função não tivesse sido declarada.

No meu html coloquei o script `exibirMensagem.js` e depois o meu `cadastro.js`

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como chamar funções Javascript em outro Javascript](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26278/como-chamar-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-javascript-em-outro-javascript)

Comment: Se nenhuma das soluções funcionou, e se sua pergunta é diferente da indicada pelo @Caputo, é necessário que você apresente maiores informações, possivelmente o código-fonte.

Comment: @user13545 adicione o código fonte dos dois arquivos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo que você está dizendo, se os arquivos estão sendo carregados na ordem correta – ou seja, o que contém a declaração da função `exibirModal` sendo carregado antes do que tenta chamar essa função –, **tudo indica que você tem um problema de escopo**.

Provavelmente a função `exibirModal` está sendo declarada dentro de outra função. Se ela não [depender de variáveis declaradas nessa outra função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1859/como-funcionam-closures-em-javascript), movê-la para fora (ou seja, para o escopo global) deve resolver. Senão, altere a declaração de algo como:

```
function exibirModal() { ...
```

para:

```
window.exibirModal = function() { ...
```

Comment: cara vlw mesmo! funcionou!

Comment: Show, só adicionei em outro arquivo como se estivesse no mesmo e funcionou aqui. Vlw

Answer (score 2):

Você poderá fazer com que o primeiro script execute uma função existente no segundo script, mas para isso deverá engatilhar a execução ao evento `onload`do documento como este exemplo (usando jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   somar(a,b); //somar() ainda será definido
});
```

Comment: Não é necessário e não deve ser este o problema. O carregamento de scripts em uma página é síncrono. A página não continua a se carregar enquanto o arquivo incluído não foi carregado. [Veja esta questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20966/posicionamento-dos-scripts-e-links-css-num-documento-html/20976#20976) para mais detalhes.

Comment: @Beterraba acho que você não entendeu a resposta. Ele quer exibir um modal mas o método não foi carregado, então ele realizará a chamada apenas no ``document ready``, onde tudo já foi carregado

Comment: Exatamente. Não tem como a função não ter sido carregada, já que o autor da pergunta explicita que ele incluiu o arquivo onde a função está declarada antes do arquivo de onde a função é chamada.

Comment: @Beterraba para mim não está explícita a ordem em que ele está carregando

Comment: Tá escrito na pergunta: "No meu html coloquei o script `exibirMensagem.js` e depois o meu `cadastro.js`". Mas beleza, só comentei pra esclarecer o ponto.

Comment: oi @Beterraba! Não quero ser chato, apenas estou policiando minha forma de interpretação e quero sua ajuda! Nos detalhes da pergunta, está explícito em qual arquivo o ``if`` em questão foi escrito? []s!

Comment: De fato, não está. Minha interpretação saiu do fato dele explicitar a ordem, o que me fez inferir que o `if` estivesse no segundo arquivo, enquanto a função no primeiro. Abraços!

Answer (score 2):

Você deve esperar que toda a página seja carregada para ter acesso aos elementos DOM, o que provavelmente acontece dentro da sua função `exibirModal()`. Sendo assim, experimente aproveitar para fazer a chamada em uma função disparada pelo evento "onload":

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    if (nome == ""){ exibirModal(); }
});
```

Comment: Não é necessário e não deve ser este o problema. O carregamento de scripts em uma página é síncrono. A página não continua a se carregar enquanto o arquivo incluído não foi carregado. [Veja esta questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20966/posicionamento-dos-scripts-e-links-css-num-documento-html/20976#20976) para mais detalhes.

Comment: Conforme apontado pelo @Beterraba, de fato, os scripts são carregados de maneira síncrona, na sequência em que foram chamados, fato aparentemente já sabido pelo OP. Assim, editei minha resposta para esclarecer melhor.

Comment: vlw pelo retorno!

Answer (score 2):

Já conhece o RequireJS ? http://requirejs.org/

O RequireJS é um carregador de arquivos JavaScript e de módulos. É uma biblioteca javascript.

Baixe em http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#requirejs
ou referencie em seu html no CDN //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.14/require.min.js

Com o RequireJS você informa que certo trecho do seu código javascript requer, ou seja, precisa que outra biblioteca javascript esteja carregada.

Exemplo (adaptando de http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) :

Digamos que seu site tem essa estrutura :

```
project-directory/
--project.html
--scripts/
----cadastro.js
----exibirMensagem.js
----require.min.js  (faça o download em http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.14/minified/require.js )
```

Então em seu HTML faça algo do tipo :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Sample Project</title>
        <!-- O atributo data-main diz para o require.js carregar
             scripts/cadastro.js depois que o require.js seja carregado. -->
        <script data-main="scripts/cadastro" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Sample Project</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Finalmente dentro de seu cadastro.js você faz algo do tipo :

```
    require(["exibirMensagem"], function(exibirMensagem) {

     if (nome == ""){ exibirModal(); }

    //Essa função será executada quando exibirMensagem.js for carregado.
    //Se exibirMensagem.js usar o método define() (mais detalhes em http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define ), então essa função só será disparada quando todos os módulos definidos forem carregados.
});
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: cara estava com o mesmo problema, e achei bacana o que você disse a respeito do RequireJS, nunca havia ouvido falar, e vai me ajudar muito. Valeu, e parabens

Comment: Vou tentar agora... fiz outros teste e não deu certo... vlw!!!

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que a ordem da incorporação dos seu script exibirMensagem.js e cadastro.js. Abra o console do navegador (geralmente F12) e tente executar a função desejada.