# Erro com javascrit em arquivo separado

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma função `javascript` para validar entrada somente de números em um campo `text` quando for `onkeypress`, `onKeyUp`, `onBlur` e `onChange`, quando eu coloco este código na pagina funciona, mais tenho varias outra pagina que precisam ser validadas por esta função, então foi centralizado esta função em um único arquivo `javascript`, porém, quando centralizo a função não funciona.
Este e o código que estou usando 
Função:

```
function SomenteCaracteresNumericos(idControle) {

        var texto = document.getElementById(idControle).value;
        var textoSeparado = texto.split('');
        var numeros = new Array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
        for (var i = 0; i < textoSeparado.length; i++) {
            var teclaValida = false;
            for (var j = 0; j < numeros.length; j++) {
                if (numeros[j] == textoSeparado[i]) {
                    teclaValida = true;
                }
            }
            if (!teclaValida)
                textoSeparado[i] = '';
        }
        document.getElementById(idControle).value = textoSeparado.join('');
    }
```

Este é o `for` que eu uso para chamar a função

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtLinhaDigitavel" runat="server" Width="390px"   onFocus="javascript:this.select();" onkeypress="javascript:SomenteCaracteresNumericos(this.id);" onKeyUp="javascript:SomenteCaracteresNumericos(this.id);" onBlur="javascript:SomenteCaracteresNumericos(this.id);" onChange="javascript:SomenteCaracteresNumericos(this.id);"></asp:TextBox>
```

Este e o erro que da na pagina:

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/26347/4808).

Comment: Fez os include do arquivo corretamente?

Comment: Qual erro você tem no console?

Comment: O erro esta na imagens.

Comment: porque não usar expressão regular? para uma coisa tão simples: `number = number.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em vez de passar o ID, passe o elemento para a função:

```
<asp:TextBox 
    ID="txtLinhaDigitavel" 
    runat="server" 
    Width="390px" 
    onFocus="javascript:this.select();" 
    onkeypress="javascript:SomenteCaracteresNumericos(this);" 
    onKeyUp="javascript:SomenteCaracteresNumericos(this);" 
    onBlur="javascript:SomenteCaracteresNumericos(this);" 
    onChange="javascript:SomenteCaracteresNumericos(this);"
></asp:TextBox>
```

E faça uma validação para verificar se o parâmetro da função é válido.

```
function SomenteCaracteresNumericos(element) {

    if (!(typeof element === "object" && element.value !== undefined)){
        console.error('Elemento não encontrado.');
        return;
    }

    var texto = element.value;
    var textoSeparado = texto.split('');
    var numeros = new Array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
    for (var i = 0; i < textoSeparado.length; i++) {
        var teclaValida = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < numeros.length; j++) {
            if (numeros[j] == textoSeparado[i]) {
                teclaValida = true;
            }
        }
        if (!teclaValida)
            textoSeparado[i] = '';
    }
    element.value = textoSeparado.join('');
}
```

---

Obs.: Não tenho certeza se o que você quiz dizer com:

> Este é o `for` que eu uso para chamar a função

Foi para falar sobre o trecho do TextBox, espero que não, mas se for tenha em mente que um id (`ID="txtLinhaDigitavel"`) deve ser único.

Comment: Ola KaduAmaral, obrigado pela ajuda, a sua solução resolveu meu problema.Se não for abusar demais por que vc fez a condição do "IF", eu não consegui entender, se possível vc pode dar um clareada na minha Ideia. Obrigado.

Comment: Opa @krispim o `if` é para ter certeza que o elemento passado no parâmetro é um campo de formulário. só pra não dar erro e interromper o _script_ onde você usa o `texto.split('')` que daria erro se o `element.value` fosse `undefined`. Ou seja, é só uma validação de segurança pra não dar erro no script. Se você sempre usar em atributos de elementos passando o `this` nunca dará erro, mas se em algum outro momento usar outras condições buscando o elemento pela classe ou pelo ID é útil pra evitar erros quando os elementos não existirem no código...

Comment: Enfim, o trecho do `IF` não é essencial para a correção do problema, considere-o como um `catch`. :)

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento KaduAmaral